# Confusion about proportionality in Kepler's 3rd law of planetary motion

Tags: notation, celestial-mechanics

I was reading about Kepler's third law on planetary motion and came across in two books $R^3\propto T^2$ and in the other $T^2\propto R^3$. So, I asked the following question on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1423309/). If both mean the same thing then the value of the constant keeps changing. $T^2/R^3$ for Earth is 2.96. If I reverse the ration then obviously the value will also change. Now this can yield wrong results while solving problems. So, what should I do?

Comment: $T^2\propto R^3$ says nothing about the constant of proportionality, and so $T^2\propto R^3$ and $ R^3\propto T^2$ are logically consistent. If it yields wrong results when applying it, you've applied it wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $\propto$ means that the expression to the right of it is equal to the expression to the left of it, but scaled by a constant. Thus this symbol is symmetric. Therefore $R^3\propto T^2$ means the same as $T^2\propto R^3$. Which way you divided these two terms does affects the magnitude of the constant scaler, but if you divide those consistently in the same order then it will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they mean the same thing.  You don't say what units you are using when you get $T^2/R^3=2.96$ for the earth, but as long as you are consistent you are fine.  Taking [Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars#Orbit_and_rotation), the semi-major axis is 1.53 AU and the orbital period is $1.88$ years.  Voila:  $1.88^2/1.53^3 =0.986$, close enough to $1$ for our accuracy